# How can I use the Fixer.io API with cloud fusion to convert currency fields (from EUR to USD) and integrate it to send data from postgres to bigquery?

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-fusion

I got my cloud fusion instance all setup and trying migrate my data (relational table by table) from postgresql to bigquery. Trying to understand how can I do it successfully? Also I have currency and amount fields in my data in USD and EUR which I want to update on a daily basis based on the currency value everyday and get it only in USD by converting it.

Can anyone help me in this scenario? and how can I  move forward to do it using Fixer API?

Comment: Hi and welcome! I think your question is slightly to broad. Think of how many possible solutions there are to your question. You need to narrow down your question to what you have already tried and how you expect it to work.
See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.